# How to know if an index in a binary heap is on an odd level?

Tags: c++, binary, heap

If I have a binary heap , with the typical properties of left neighbor of position "pos" being (2*pos)+1 while right neighbor is (2*pos)+2 and parent node in (pos-1) )/ 2, how can I efficiently determine if a given index represents a node on an odd level (with the level of the root being level 0) ?

Comment: Since I am relatively new here, could someone please clarify what is wrong with this question ? format ? tags ? I did search if too see if an answer already existed.

Comment: I would say the parity of `log2(pos + 1)`

Comment: The tooltips on the vote buttons summarize the sentiments the votes convey. Personally, I'd say this isn't a C++ question, nor a programming question, so it may be considered off-topic. Moreover, it's asking for a simple mathematical computation, so it may be considered to "lack research effort". But ultimately users can cast votes for any personal reason they like.

Comment: I see. I actually did research it but couldn't find anything helpful. But fair enough, its the last piece of a larger puzzle, which is to create a data structure that can retrieve information faster than a binary search tree by utilizing a binary hash that takes advantage SIMD instructions to diminish cache misses. Funny that this small detail was the part I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: This is a more complete answer based on Jarod42's comment.)

The formula you want is:

```
floor(log2(pos+1)) mod 2
```

To understand why, look at the levels of the first few nodes:

```
           0               Level: 0
      1          2                1
   3    4     5     6             2
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14           3

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 2
...
6 -> 2
7 -> 3
...
```

The first step is to find a function that will map node numbers to level numbers in this way. Adding one to the number and taking a base 2 logarithm will give you almost (but not quite) what you want:

```
log2 (0+1) = log2 1 = 0
log2 (1+1) = log2 2 = 1
log2 (2+1) = log2 3 = 1.6 (roughly)
log2 (3+1) = log2 4 = 2
....
log2 (6+1) = log2 7 = 2.8 (roughly)
log2 (7+1) = log2 8 = 3
```

You can see from this that rounding down to the nearest integer in each case will give you the level of each node, hence giving us `floor(log2(pos+1))`.

As Jarod42 said, it's then a case of looking at the parity of the level number, which just involves taking the number `mod 2`. This will give either `0` (the level is even) or `1` (the level is odd).

Comment: And there are efficient ways to compute `log2` - shifting, table lookups, specific hardware instructions, etc.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Thanks, good point. Worth also noting that a quick Google for 'fast log2' seems fruitful for anyone looking for more information on how to do it.

Comment: So basically, I need to call ceil on the result of log2 (I + 1) and then I get the answer by the parity of the result. Awesome, thank you very much sir.

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped. I meant floor.

Comment: Wait, with floor, level 2 will be considered an odd level when it should be even.

Comment: @BrunoAyllon: That's not true actually. If you consider `3` from level `2`, then `floor(log2(3+1)) mod 2` = `floor(log2(4)) mod 2` = `floor(2) mod 2` = `2 mod 2` = `0`, which indicates that `3` is on an even level. Similarly for `6`, `floor(log2(6+1)) mod 2` = `floor(log2(7)) mod 2` = `2 mod 2` = `0`.